# Binding Complex array data returned from ajax call to viewmodel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a retrieveEntity web service method that returns fields as json strings and arrays. I am having trouble binding these fields to text boxes, while keeping the view model intact. First I make an ajax call to initialize my data and save it. Then inside my viewmodel I retrirve the values, and bind to the desired text box. Here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
 jQuery(function () {
     myViewModel = new viewmodel();
     ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
 });


 var invoice = function () {
     var initializeURL = "ajaxwebservicecalls.asmx/RetrieveEmptyEntity";
     $.ajax({
         type: "Post",
         url: initializeURL,
         data: {},
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function retrieveemptyesuccess(msg) {
             passedmodel = (msg.d.Data);
             var data = ko.mapping.fromJS(passedmodel);
             var x = $.toJSON(passedmodel)
         },
         Error: function initializefail(msg) { alert(msg) }

     });

 }
```

Here is a small snippet of what X returns:

```
{
"Entities": {
    "Entity": [{
        "Index": "1",
        "Name": "BatchNumber",
        "Value": ""
    }, {
        "Index": "2",
        "Name": "InvoiceNumber",
        "Value": ""
    }]
},
"APInvoiceHeader": {
    "VoucherNumber": "",
    "PayLocationID": "",
    "InvoiceDescription": "",
    "InvoiceTypeID": "",
    "TermsRuleID": "",
    "TaxTypeID": "",
    "RecurringInvoice": 0,
    "APInvoiceItems": [{
        "FixedAssetReferences": [{
            "FixedAssetReferenceId": 0,
            "FixedAssetReferenceIdSpecified": true,
            "FormattedGLAccount": ""
        }]
    }
```

Next I construct my viewmodel based on the data returned:

```
        var passedmodel;
        var myViewModel;
        var viewmodel = function () {

            this.invoice = ko.observable(new invoice());
            this.arrayentity = ko.observableArray([new invoice("ff"), new invoice("dd"), new invoice("zz"), new invoice("rr")]);

            this.RetrieveEntity = function () {
                var retrieveURL = "ajaxwebservicecalls.asmx/RetrieveEntity";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: retrieveURL,
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function retrievesuccess(msg) {
                        passedmodel = msg.d.Data;

    myViewModel.invoice(ko.mapping.fromJS(passedmodel, {}, myViewModel)); }
```

//I want to be able to Use the above, and then in the HTML binding specify for example:

```
data-bind="value:myViewModel.invoice().APInvoiceHeader.VoucherNumber"
```

or

```
data-bind="value:myViewModel.arrayentity().Entities.Entity()[0].Name"
```

However the binding syntax gives me an error. And instead i have parse the viewmodel and can't use it as a whole:

```
myViewModel.invoice(ko.mapping.fromJS(passedmodel.APInvoiceHeader, {}, myViewModel));
```

or

```
myViewModel.arrayentity([(ko.mapping.fromJS(passedmodel.Entities.Entity[0])),    (ko.mapping.fromJS(passedmodel.Entities.Entity[1]))]);
```

and the HTML bindings then looks like

```
  data-bind="value:myViewModel.invoice().VoucherNumber
```

or

```
 data-bind="value:myViewModel.arrayentity()[0].Name"
```

which binds fine but that's not how I want the viewmodel to look like.
                                                                                           The reason I need to keep the viewmodel in as one and parse or navigate through is is because I need to next update value on screen, which updates the viewmodel, then convert the viewmodel back to JS, and pass it to another ajax call that saves the new data.

Can anyone please help? Any tips would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle of this. It will make troubleshooting your problem easier.